# SQL Server : json list remove property from every element

Tags: json, sql-server

I have as the following structure

```
{
 "property":"something"
  "list":[
    {"name":"me", "title":"mr", "gender":"m"},
    {"name":"she", "title":"ms"},
    {"name":"aaa"}
   ]
}
```

The list can have any number of elements. There will not be always the same structure for the list element.

I need to remove the title for each element in the list. I am using Microsoft sql server. I have read about Json_modify but I cannot provide a path to the element as I don't know if there will be 2 or 100 elements.

How can I delete every property of an element from the list?

Comment: JSON game begins from `SQL Server 2016`. Which ver are you using?

Comment: @PrabhatG i'm using SQL server 2017